# Query Values of Columns with Specific Number of Char

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to split the value of single column into two columns shows the 2 characters and 4 characters only, for example I have this query:

```
SELECT colA FROM TableA
```

return:

```
+ colA +
+------+
+ valA +
+ valB +
+  va  +
+  vc  +
+      +
+ valC +
```

so my expecting result is:

```
+ colA + colWith2Char+ colwith4Char +
+------+-------------+--------------+ 
+ valA +             +     valA     + 
+ valB +             +     valB     +
+  va  +     va      +              +
+  vc  +     vc      +              +
+      +             +              +
+ valC +             +     valC     +
```

I tried to used the char_length but is there a better way how can I easily get this output?

Any solution on suggestions thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use IF statements to conditionally pull values based on their length.

```
SELECT colA,
    IF(LENGTH(colA) = 2, colA, NULL) AS colWith2Char,
    IF(LENGTH(colA) = 4, colA, NULL) AS colWith4Char 
FROM TableA;
```

Note: you could also do this with the more standard CASE statement, but it's a little more verbose.

```
SELECT colA,
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(colA) = 2 THEN colA ELSE NULL END AS colWith2Char,
    CASE WHEN LENGTH(colA) = 4 THEN colA ELSE NULL END AS colWith4Char 
FROM TableA;
```

Comment: Perfect!, I forgot that I can have condition during selecting columns rather doing conditions in where clause.